# Check if subdocument in range complies with a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a mongoDB query.

I have several documents which I query with following results:

```
{
    "_id" : 1000.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-05-25T00:20:00.000Z"),
    "value" : true
}

{
    "_id" : 1000.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-05-25T00:26:00.000Z"),
    "value" : false
}

{
    "_id" : 1000.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2018-05-25T00:30:00.000Z"),
    "value" : false
}
```

The original documents are filtered so that I get only document within the last 15 minutes before *now* and there is no way of knowing how many entries are in that time range.

I need to expand my existing query so that it returns a status based on the "value". If there are *no true* I need a status *0*, if there is *at least 1 but not only true* I need a status *1*, and if there are *only true* I need a status 2.

For example:

```
{
    "_id" : 1000,
    "status" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : 1001,
    "status" : 2
}
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this using mongoDB? Or would it be better/easier to do it on java side? Note that there are several _id in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gather all values from each group into one array (using `$group` and `$push`) and then use [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) to apply your logic. To determine whether array contains any `true` value or all values are `true` you can use [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) and [$allElementsTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/):

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            values: { $push: "$value" }
        }
    },
    {$unwind:"$values"},
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            status: {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $allElementsTrue: "$values" }, then: 2 },
                        { case: { $anyElementTrue: "$values" }, then: 1 },
                    ],
                    default: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This approach seems the most straight forward one. However I get a 2 (allElementsTrue) value regardless of the content of the values array. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: I think I figured out the why behind getting always an allElementsTrue = true.

When running the query as it is above I get the results as

`
{
    "_id" : 1498.0,
    "values" : [ 
        [ 
            false, 
            true
        ]
    ]
}
`
and according to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/), allElemetsTrue does not descend into the nested array but evaluates the array at top-level.
How can I make "values" become a top level array?

Comment: @SebastianR I thought that your three sample documents always have `value` as simple boolean. Since they have the same _id I guess those docs are a result of some unknown previous aggregations (since you can't have duplicate _id in Mongo). In that case you don't need `$unwind`. Do I understand correctly ?